# opening Windows server folders as simply as local

Tags: file-sharing, windows-server-2003

I have few servers (in different domains) where I can copy files from another server only - let me call it "X".
If I want to copy any file from my personal computer, I connect to "X" through Total Commander like program, copy files, then log on "X" through Remote Desktop Connection and finally copy mentioned files to target servers.

Is there any way to speed up this process? 
Unfortunately, although part of servers have Power Shell, mentioned "X" haven't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XCOPY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to copy files between two servers while being on a third one.

Just use Administrative shares like `\host1\C$\pathtofile\file.txt` or use Shared directories to copy from one to another.

Lets asume you have 3 servers: X Y Z.

You are on Y and want to copy files from X to Z directly.

Use `XCOPY` and provide `\X\C$\pathtofile\file.txt` as source path and `\Z\C$\pathtofile\file.txt` as destination path.

It will use RAM on Y server and possibly some files will be temporarily stored on the drive (temp) but it will be faster then copy form X to Y and from Y to Z.